# 404 error for css and js after gulp production

Tags: gulp

I am using sage theme, When i run normal gulp command it renders `main.css` and the page is working fine.

But in case after i run `gulp --production` it compiles the main css and gives `main.css?v1506320180` in the `dist` folder , and in the console it says error 404 main.css not found

Answer (score 0):

Update to this and this and has been fixed `/lib/setup.php`

```
 wp_enqueue_style('sage/css', Assets\asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, current_time('gis'));
 wp_enqueue_script('sage/js', Assets\asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], current_time('gis'), true);
```